# What is the wisdom behind going to the Eid prayer from one path and returning from another?

Tags: salat, sunnah, islamic-philosophy, eid

Most of us know that is sunnah to go to the Eid prayer from one way and return from a different way.

> Narrated Jabir bin `Abdullah:
>
> On the Day of 'Id the Prophet (ﷺ) used to return (after offering the `Id prayer) through a way different from that by which he went.
>
> (Sahih [al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/13/35), see also similar narrations on the authority of abu Hurairah in Jami' [at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/5/12), sunan [ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1313590) and on the authority of ‘Abdur-Rahman bin Sa’d bin ‘Ammar bin Sa’d in sunan [ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1313560))

I want to ask:
What is the wisdom behind going to the Eid prayer from one path and returning from another if any? (I'd like to have sourced interpretations "Scholar X says's "...", Scholar Y ...")